# UIElement's position relative to another image in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that is basically a maximized Canvas. On the canvas I have a Border, that has an Image child--think of a picture of a map.

```
<Canvas x:Name="MapCanvas" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Border x:Name="MapBorder">
            <Image x:Name="MapImage" Source="/ngme;component/Resources/map.jpg" MouseWheel="MapImage_MouseWheel" 
                MouseLeftButtonDown="MapImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="MapImage_MouseMove" 
                MouseLeftButtonUp="MapImage_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </Border>
</Canvas>
```

Now, what I want to do is add my custom UIElements on specific points on the map and keep them there, always on their relative position, when I pan or scale the map image.

Panning and scaling is implemented with TranslateTransform and ScalingTransform:

```
private void CreateMap() {
    MapImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    transformGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
    transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform());
    MapImage.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
}

private void MapImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)MapImage.RenderTransform)
        .Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    _start = e.GetPosition(MapBorder);
    _origin = new Point(tt.X, tt.Y);
    MapImage.CaptureMouse();
}

private void MapImage_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (MapImage.IsMouseCaptured) {
        var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)MapImage.RenderTransform)
            .Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        Vector v = _start - e.GetPosition(MapBorder);
        tt.X = _origin.X - 0.35 * v.X;
        tt.Y = _origin.Y - 0.35 * v.Y;
    }
}

private void MapImage_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
    var group = (TransformGroup)MapImage.RenderTransform;
    var st = (ScaleTransform)group.Children[1];
    double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
    st.ScaleX += zoom;
    st.ScaleY += zoom;    
}
```

I can position my custom elements on the image, before making any manipulation and I could get them the stay in their position by "following" the movement of the image (using the same `v` vector in `MapImage_MouseMove`), but I don't know how to calculate their new position when the image gets scaled--whatever I try they just get messed up all around the image.

Is there a way to "attach" the UIElement to a specific point on the image? Or alternatively, what would be the way to determine the new Top and Left values?

For the latter this is what I tried adding to `MapImage_MouseWheel`:

```
foreach (Marker marker in MyCustomElements.Values)
{
    var loctt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)marker.RenderTransform)
        .Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    double left = (Canvas.GetLeft(marker) - MapCanvas.ActualWidth / 2) * zoom + MapCanvas.ActualWidth / 2;
    double top = (Canvas.GetTop(marker) - MapCanvas.ActualHeight / 2) * zoom + MapCanvas.ActualHeight / 2;
    loctt.X = Canvas.GetLeft(marker) - left;
    loctt.Y = Canvas.GetTop(marker) - top;
}
```

Comment: In case this is really a map, have you considered using a full-featured map control?

Comment: Scaling a canvas along with its children is trivial in WPF, so you must mean you want the children to stay in their correct relative position but not change size. See marked duplicates. If that's not what you want and want the children to scale in size as well, see `Viewbox`. If you have any additional questions, post a new question, but make sure in any new question that you include a good [mcve], rather than the code fragments as seen above.